Arm64 Linux find pte of address at kernel space
I'm building a kernel module for research currently, and I need to find the pte of addresses at kernel space.I'm current building on linux4.19(armv8).
Below is my attempt to get pte.
(edited my code thanks to @Siguza ‘s comment, and improved the reading (used READ_ONCE)and naming of some variables.)
pte_t *lookup_address_arm64(unsigned long addr, unsigned int *level)
{
    pgd_t *pgdp;
    pud_t *pudp, pud;
    pmd_t *pmdp, pmd;

    *level = 0;

    pgd_t *pgd_base;
    unsigned long phys_addr;
    // read TTBR1_EL1 to get pgd, tried pgd_offset_k but init_mm not defined
    phys_addr = read_sysreg(ttbr1_el1) & ((1UL << 48) - 2); // get baddr
    
    // convert to virt
    pgd_base = (pgd_t *)phys_to_virt(phys_addr);

    pgdp = pgd_offset_raw(pgd_base, addr);
    
    if (pgd_none(READ_ONCE(*pgdp)))
        return NULL;

    pudp = pud_offset(pgdp, addr);
    pud = READ_ONCE(*pudp);
    
    if (pud_none(pud))
        return NULL;
    *level = 3;
    
    if (pud_sect(pud))
        return (pte_t *)pudp;

    pmdp = pmd_offset(pudp, addr);
    pmd = READ_ONCE(*pmdp);
    
    if (pmd_none(pmd))
        return NULL;
    *level = 2;
    if (pmd_sect(pmd))
        return (pte_t *)pmdp;

    *level = 1;
    return pte_offset_kernel(pmdp, addr);
}


This time it's not causing kernel panic but at linereturn (pte_t *)pudp; it returned.
The address I was trying to find pte is in the direct mapping of all physical memory area.
The code returned because pud is a big page pte. But I've disabled big page by unsetting CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_ALWAYS at .config. Also I double-checked it by # cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i huge
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB

I have printed out more key variable values as follows:
[   15.990883] [look_up_addr] addr at 0xffff800040000000 pgd_base at 0xffff8000017f8000
[   15.993070] [look_up_addr] addr at 0xffff800040000000 pgdp at 0xffff8000017f8800
[   15.993835] [look_up_addr] addr at 0xffff800040000000 pgd val = 0xbdff7803
[   15.994384] [look_up_addr] addr at 0xffff800040000000 pudp at 0xffff80007dff7008
[   15.994812] [look_up_addr] addr at 0xffff800040000000 pud val = 0xe8000080000f11

kernel panic before(solved):
[   20.339178] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffc17f40000800
[   20.342033] Mem abort info:
[   20.342592]   ESR = 0x96000004
[   20.343163]   Exception class = DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[   20.344075]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[   20.346614]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[   20.347305] Data abort info:
[   20.347707]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000004
[   20.348805]   CM = 0, WnR = 0
[   20.353096] swapper pgtable: 4k pages, 48-bit VAs, pgdp = 00000000a2e904bd
[   20.354361] [ffffc17f40000800] pgd=0000000000000000
[   20.355638] Internal error: Oops: 96000004 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[   20.357312] Dumping ftrace buffer:
[   20.358719]    (ftrace buffer empty)


Where is the phys_addr << 16 coming from?

@Siguza maybe that's the problem? I originally thought that the base address of PGD is obtained by shifting the [47:1] of TLBR1_EL1 to the high [63:17].

How did you get that idea? The largest physical address space supported by the ARMv8-A architecture in any configuration is 52 bits, but even that is an optional extension, with most chips only supporting a 48-bit physical address space. So that << 16 is definitely wrong.

@Siguza So how can I get the baseaddr of PGD from TTBR1_EL1? My setting is 48bits and 4-level page table, my page size is 4KB.

Just remove the line phys_addr = phys_addr << 16 from your code.

@Siguza Thank you and it's not causing kernel panic now, but it still cannot find pte of the address. I've updated my problem.

Okay, so with full 48-bit VAs and 4k pages, translation tables start at L0, not L1. But ideally you'd read TCR_EL1.T1SZ to find the level at which translation starts (and TCR_EL1.TG1, either to account for translation granule, or at least to have a hardcoded check for 4k).
